# How to combine integers from rows and make it one distinct row

Tags: mysql

My current SQL query outputs something like this:

```
Team    Amount
 A      10.00
 B      20.00
 C      40.00
 C      30.00
```

I was wondering how I could make the query only output a single row for multiple "teams" and add the integers together for all teams - basically all teams display only once and the amount is the sum of all that team's entries in the database.

For example, the correct way I want the example above to output would be like this:

```
Team    Amount
 A      10.00
 B      20.00
 C      70.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a straightforward sum and group-by:

```
select team, sum(amount) as amount
from mytable
group by team
order by team
```

It is unclear whether you want arbitrary (ie no) ordering, ordering by team, or ordering by the sum. If you want to order by the sum, change the order-by clause to:

```
order by sum(amount)
```